# create a QThread to make changes

Tags: qt, qthread

I'm trying to monitor changes in a folder using QFileSystemWatcher, and whenever changes happen they will be reflected in the GUI.

The idea is that I have a folder that gets updated every second with new images, and I need to display those images in sequence

nevertheless, the changes happen very fast, and the GUI freezes.

how can I make this line run in a different thread whenever there's a change in the folder.

`QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(directoryChanged(QString)), w, SLOT(showModified(QString)));`

or how can I make the code that creates reflections on the GUI run in a separate thread?

Comment: Updating `Qt` widgets from a thread other than that on which `main` is running is not supported.  You should provide more information regarding exactly what you're trying to achieve -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

To make `QFileSystemWatcher` work in a separate thread you can do:

1. Create new thread - `auto thread = new QThread;`
2. Create new file system watcher - `auto watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher;`
3. Move `watcher` to `thread` - `watcher->moveToThread(thread);`
4. Make connections

   `connect(thread, &QThread::finished, watcher, &QObject::deleteLater);`

   `connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QObject::deleteLater);`

   `connect(watcher, &QFileSystemWatcher::directoryChanged, w, &<YourWidgetClassName>::showMidified, Qt::QueuedConnection);`
5. Start thread `thread->start();`
6. Setup `watcher` with `addPath` or `addPaths`
7. Do not forget call `thread->quit();` when it's not needed or before application exits

So about problem of bunch images rendering in GUI.

I suggest you to use `QImage` to load and scale images for `QPixmap` to be created and rendered in GUI. Here `QtConcurrent::run` can be used per image to preform an image loading in a separate thread. It returns a `QFuture` object, that can be tracked with a `QFutureWatcher` object, that emits a `finished` signal, when a watched future is complete. Once connected to a `QFutureWatcher::finished` signal you can handle `QFuture`'s result to assign a loaded `QImage` to `QPixmap`.

So, you need a code like this for `QFileSystemWatcher::directoryChanged` signal handler:

```
QStringList filenames = <some code to get new image filenames to render>;

auto loadImage = [](const QString &aFilename) -> QPixmap {
    auto image = QImage(aFilename).scaled(200, 200, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    return QPixmap::fromImage(image);
};

for (auto &filename : filenames) {
    auto pixmap = QPixmap(200, 200); //create empty pixmap of desired size
    auto label = new QLabel;
    label->setPixmap(pixmap);
    m_layout->addWidget(label);

    auto future = QtConcurrent::run(loadImage, filename);
    auto watcher = new QFutureWatcher<QPixmap>(this);
    connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<QPixmap>::finished, this, [watcher, label]() { label->setPixmap(watcher->result()); });
    connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<QPixmap>::finished, watcher, &QFutureWatcher<QPixmap>::deleteLater);
    watcher->setFuture(future);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I still have a problem that my GUI freezes. The idea is that I have a folder that gets updated every second with new images, and I need to display those images in sequence.

Comment: GUI freezes not because of watcher in thread. How do you load and render images? I suppose you use a `QPixmap` to load image and `QLabel`s to render it (or maybe you have a `QListView` with associated model which is better anyway).

Comment: @AbubakerGaber If you have a new problem you should post a new question showing the problematic code -- preferably as a [mcve].

Comment: @G.M. no not a new problem, it's the same issue it wasn't fixed

Comment: @AbubakerGaber, i've expanded my answer with a general approach for image loading in separate thread